# ValueError: bad input shape (1, 4) in sklearn.naive_bayes.GaussianNB

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gaussian, valueerror, naivebayes

I started to learn machine learning, currently Naive Bayes/

### My python script

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[0,1],[1,0]])
y = np.array([0,0,1,1])
print(x)
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
x = x.reshape(1,-1)
y = y.reshape(1,-1)
clf.fit(x,y)
a = clf.predict([[1,1]])
print(a)
```

#### Error

The error is:

```
[[0 0]
[1 1]
[0 1]
[1 0]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 9, in <module>
    clf.fit(x,y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 182, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 526, in check_X_y
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 562, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape (1, 4)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Remove the `x = x.reshape(1,-1)`, this is the cause of your error. x becomes a 1D array of length 8, which can't fit y (length 4).

Comment: @Nuageux after that also i m getting that error

Comment: My mistake, you should also remove: `y = y.reshape(1,-1)`. Why did you wanted to reshape, any particular reason?

Comment: @Nuageux at first i didn't used reshape but at that time it was showing this
    <br> DeprecationWarning: Passing 1d arrays as data is deprecated in 0.17 and will raise ValueError in 0.19. Reshape your data either using X.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or X.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample. DeprecationWarning)

Comment: Few questions: Did you try the same code you provide here without the two reshape line, and do you still have the same error? If yes, what's your python version? (On 2.7 I don't have any problem). Finally, as your data doesn't have a single feature nor containes a single sample, reshaping your data has a real impact of the dimension of it, be careful with the error message, sometimes it doesn't correspond to your case.

Comment: @Nuageux no i don't have the same error(Its a warning) now.
and yes i tried the same code before

Comment: Can you provide the warning? Just a check, do you obtain `a = [0]` as expected?

Comment: @Nuageux yes i m getting a = [0]

Comment: for ``a = clf.predict([[1,0]])``  
I m getting ``[[0 0]
 [1 1]
 [0 1]
 [1 0]]
a = [0]``

Comment: Well that depends on the training data and algorithm. As @Nuageux said in his answer, NaiveBayes needs more data to predict such non linear problem. If still not satisfied, please post it as a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I was saying in the comments, no need to reshape. You get this error before (i.e. no with the code you provide) since you code was working after that.

Considering the part where you obtain always 0 as the prediction, it was due to your data. Naive Bayes needs more samples to separate the classes, two samples per class for a non-linear problem is not sufficient.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB

def GNB(x,y):
    clf = GaussianNB()
    clf.fit(x,y)
    a = clf.predict(x)
    print(a)

x = np.array([[0,0],[1,1],[0,1],[1,0]])
y = np.array([0,0,1,1])
GNB(x,y)
# Output : [0,0,0,0]

x = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,1],[1,0],[3,4],[-2,2],[-3,2],[-4,-2]])
y = np.array([0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1])
GNB(x,y)
# [0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
```

Look at my two examples. In the first case (the one you provide), the NB does not succeed the separate the data. On the 2nd example (still non-linearly), the NB succeed to return the right classes as there was a sufficient number of samples.

I create a function for clarity, but you can just add more samples to your example and you will see it works.
Hope this helps and solve your problem.